# Change border color for gframe widget

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I am working with tcltk in gwidgets and want to make the border of a gframe black instead of the light gray color it has by defualt so it is more visible.  So far I cannot find anything in the documentation that would help me do this.

Comment: With `gWidgets2` the underling Tk ttk_frame widget is accessed via `obj =frame_name$widget`. From there you can call `tkconfigure(obj, style="...")` for some style you want to define. But it isn't as trivial as setting a `bg` or `background` property as far as I can recall.

Comment: @jverzani Thank You!